# Cann't connect from another server to Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I can connect locally like normal :

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

I can also connect

```
sqlplus sys/pass@hostname:1521/servicename as sysdba
```

the service I get from when I do `lsrnctl status` but when I try to connect this from other system where oracle is running I get following error:

```
ORA-12543: TNS: Destination host unreachable
```

the command I used is

```
sqlplus sys/pass@hostname:1521/servicename as sysdba
```

which with the same I can connect locally but not from remove server. I try to check

```
telnet 192.1368.0.15 1521
```

given me below error

```
telnet: connnect to address hostname: no route to host:
```

I try to disable the iptables from the target host where oracle is installed no luck. What is wrong with this? Everything works locally I can connect and even ping the TNS.

One thing I notice my SID is `orcl` but the service instance that shows in `lsnrctl status` it shows as `orclXDB`

Comment: Looks like your instance didn't register with the listener. What happens if you connect locally and run `alter system register`. Also what does `tnsping hostname` give you? Are you aware that you the "hostname" part isn't really a "hostname" but a "TNS name" - as defined in `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: when I run alter system register it says system altered... when I do tnsping and the ip it replay OK ( 0 msec)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : no, there is absolutely nothing in the error messages that looks like the instance did not register. Also 'hostname' is not a name from tnsnames.ora but it is the name of the database

Comment: @miracle173: of course hostname needs to resolve to the alias defined in `tnsnames.ora`. [From the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1142625) "*You must enter (...) a net service name to connect to a database*". If `lsnrctl status` doesn't show the service than this does indicate the instance didn't register.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I wanted to write "Also 'hostname' is not a name from tnsnames.ora but it is the name of the database **server**". hi4ppl uses [Easy Connection Identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#BABFAGHC) and not a tnsname.

Comment: @hi4ppl: 'telnet: connnect to address hostname: no route to host:'  shows that there is some problem not related to oracle database. You have to solve this first.

Comment: `telnet 192.1368.0.15 1521` given me below error `telnet: connnect to address hostname: no route to host:` - I see you fat-fingered the IP address in this call. Could you type a correct IP and try this again?